# Azure Cosmos Python "Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a simple item hosted in my "apps" container in Cosmos DB as such:

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "apps": "testApp2",
    "name": "testApp2",
    "description": "I'm a test app2!",
    "developer": "test2 developer",
    "platforms": "Android",
    "created_at": "6/9/2021",
    "updated_at": "6/14/2021
}
Parition key = 'apps'
```

However, when I try and invoke the function read_item on my container proxy (with appId = 2)

```
appContainer = database.get_container_client('apps')
return appContainer.read_item(item=str(appId), partition_key='apps')
```

I get an error stating **"Message: Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system"**

I am confused by this because I have the exact same way of reading an item through the container proxy for my users container and it works fine. Along with this, when I use this code snippet

```
appQuery = "SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.id = '%s'" %(appId,)
items = list(appContainer.query_items(
    query=appQuery,
    enable_cross_partition_query=True
))
return items[0]
```

My app with id 2 is found correctly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the following line of code:

```
return appContainer.read_item(item=str(appId), partition_key='apps')
```

to

```
return appContainer.read_item(item=str(appId), partition_key='testApp2')
```

What you're doing is that you're specifying the name of the partition key attribute (`apps`). What you need to do is specify the value of the partition key (`testApp2`).

Comment: That did work, thank you. I was assuming since my container partition key was 'apps', then that's what I should be inserting there, instead of my individual value for each item.

Comment: That's a common mistake :). Essentially you're asking Cosmos DB to do a point search based on the id and partition key value when you call `read_item`.

Comment: @GauravMantri  Can you tell what is the default partition key.Is it id?    It is mandatory to know this while deleting an item using container.delete_item() but I am unable to find a way to identify this Partition key for a container I already have :)